# nodejs to return json response from an api call made within nodejs

Tags: node.js

How to return the response from the API call within nodejs. I can see the body from the response printed onto the console. But how do i print or return as final output when i call http://localhost:8080/

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/json' });
    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'hostname': 'XXX',
        'path': 'XXX',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'api-key': 'XXX'
        },
        'maxRedirects': 20
    };
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
        var chunks = [];
        res.on("data", function (chunk) { chunks.push(chunk); });
        res.on("end", function (chunk) {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            console.log(body.toString());

        });
        res.on("error", function (error) { console.error(error); });
    });
    var postData = JSON.stringify({ "TEST DATA"});
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 'Content-Type' in res.writeHead to 'application/json' since you are returning JSON data.

```js
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
```

You can rename the res variable inside the https.request callback to apiResponse to avoid confusion between the incoming request's res and the API response. Then use res.end(body) to send the API response body back to the client. Something like this,

```js
var apiRequest = https.request(options, function (apiResponse) {
    var chunks = []
    apiResponse.on("data", function (chunk) { chunks.push(chunk) })
    apiResponse.on("end", function () {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks)
        res.end(body) // Send API response to the client
    });
    apiResponse.on("error", function (error) { console.error(error) })
})
```